# What is the height of the IKEA BILLY plinth?

Tags: furniture

If any owner can do a quick measurement and help me out, **what is the exact height *(cm. not in.)* of the IKEA BILLY plinth?** *Se the image below:*

[image]

I need the exact height to the bottom of the first shelf because I want to order one *(several actually, I have many tangible books)*, pop the plinth, put some tiny variable-height legs for some extra support so I can easily vacuum under it. *I hate dust and it hates me.*

I somehow concluded it's 10cm but I'm not really sure and also not feeling like making a trip right now to IKEA just to measure it. Their email support will probably reply on Monday so maybe I get lucky here.:)

Thanks!

***PS**: In centimeters please.*

***PPS**: I'm quite shocked there's no `IKEA` tag.*

Comment: "The core of this site is around parts of your home that are typically included when you buy or sell it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances." [DIY Help page](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I'm surprised there's even a furniture tag, and and IKEA tag would certainly be out of place.

Comment: Not sure if I would call anything associated with the Billy a "plinth" (in the sense that it is sturdy)... I have several and the structure is really all in the sides (and how vertical you keep them). If you put feet anywhere under it that aen't directly supporting the sides, you are gonna have a bad time

Comment: @JeffMeden So the actual support of the bookcase is in the sides, the plinth is primarily for aesthetics?

Comment: Absolutely.  I happen to have a tape and am sitting right next to one so today just might be your lucky day.  The material (hesitate to call it wood but i guess it is) you see at the front below the first shelf is just a very thin piece of fiber.  The first (lowest) shelf is held in the same way the middle shelf and top is, via two cam screws and *plastic* cam locks in the shelf.  For what its worth the space under the first shelf measures 11.75cm high

Comment: @JeffMeden Thanks a lot! Then, in case it gets wobbly, I'll just slap one of [these](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/observator-suport-in-cruce__20200_PE091016_S5.JPG) on the back. It makes *(less reliable)* wood structures stiff as a corpse. :) You should change your comments into an answer so I can accept it. I bet others will find them useful.

Comment: @JeffMeden, you really should consolidate your comments into an answer.

Comment: If you want to make it really, really stiff, use a sheet of 1/4" plywood instead of the cheap cardboard backboard they give you, and screw it down in as many places as possible, ideally, glue it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I would call anything associated with the Billy a "plinth" (in the sense that it is sturdy)... I have several and the structure is really all in the sides (and how vertical you keep them). If you put support anywhere under it that isn't directly supporting the sides, you are gonna have a bad time.

The material (hesitate to call it wood but i guess it is) you see at the front below the first shelf is just a very thin piece of fiberboard. The first (lowest) shelf is held in the same way the middle shelf and top is, via two cam screws and plastic cam locks in the shelf. For what its worth, the space under the first shelf measures 11.75cm high.

As to your plan to use an X brace, that would prevent the unit from swaying but remember this is all fiberboard (and rather loosely pressed at that) so any single point support that exerts a lot of force is going to split it open like a soft burrito.  The most popular way to make the Billy into something sturdy is to gang it together (my installation has 5 of them across the wall, each anchored to the wall at the middle and at the top, and to the one next to it with screws in both directions).

And lastly, why would you remove the front face and put feet on it with the intention that it will become easier to clean under? IMO the purpose of that little face is to keep dust and other random bits from settling back there in the first place.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. I plan to join 3 pieces (2x80cm + 1x40cm) into a 2m unit. As long as the plinth is not that important, I'll make it work and paint the plinth holes in the sides to 'hide' them a bit.

Comment: Yes that piece in and of itself is completely ancillary, its held in place by dowels.

Comment: I've had Billy bookcases here for some years, and I've just checked and got more like 8cm. So you'd want to check before buying. Ikea use the term "plinth" for floor-level cosmetic front panels (also in their kitchens). (This is all UK)

Comment: Ikea recently redid (at least for the units sold in the US) the Billy line making the shelves stiffer and a bit thicker, and probably changed the overall layout to match.  The units I have are just about a year old.

Comment: The little face is very bad at prevent dust from settling there.  It works well at hiding the fact dust has settled.  Someone who is allergic to dust probably needs to remove it.